# Read float numbers form .dat file into a vector in C++

Tags: c++

I am pretty new to C++ and I have a question:

I have a given .dat file with float numbers. Since the number of entries of the .dat file will be unknown in princple, I thought about using a vector. This procedure works fine, if the .dat file contains integers only. However, I fail to achieve the upgrade to floats.

To be precise, consider a file Test.dat:

```
    5.7
    90.1
```

and the corresponding code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<float> vec;
    ifstream fin("Test.dat");
    int num;

    while (fin >> num)
        vec.push_back(num);


    for(int counti=0; counti<2 ; counti++)
    {
    cout<<vec[counti]<<endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```

with output:

```
5
2.21326e-038 .
```

As mentioned earlier, changing to `vector<int> vec;` and adapting the data accordingly, results in a satisfactory result.

I appreciate any hint or solutions and comments to the above problem.
Thank you very much,
Marc

Comment: First thing to do is use `float` or `double` instead of `int` for `num`'s data type. You can't read floating point numbers into an integer.

Comment: You're reading a double into an int variable so you're loosing some information. Change `int num` to `double num`

Comment: Suggestion: `vec` knows how big it is. Replace `counti<2` with `counti<vec.size()` so you can't be fooled by having too few (or too many) items in `vec`. A more modern solution would take advantage of range-based for loops and look like `for (float val: vec) cout << val << endl;`

Comment: ok, great, thanks a lot, I missed that declaration!
I think that solves the issue. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [user4581301](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4581301/user4581301) mentioned, you data types need to match. Change `int num` to `float num`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<float> vec;
    ifstream fin("Test.dat");
    float num;

    while (fin >> num)
        vec.push_back(num);


    for(int counti=0; counti<2 ; counti++)
    {
    cout<<vec[counti]<<endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```